# Angular Bootstrap Typeahead dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, angularjs-digest

I have an Angular ui-boostrap typeahead component that is working correctly until I added one requirement to the whole function. I want to call the backend for the suggested results just after user types in 3 letters. It is done correctly but my problem is that the results are visible only when users type in the 4th letter. Is there any way to bypass this, by forcing it to refresh the UI just after user types in the 3rd letter. 
Code is :

```
HTLM 
<input name="states" id="states" type="text" ng-model="vm.cityName"
uib-typeahead="municipality as  municipality.city + ' (' + municipality.name + ') '+municipality.zipCode for municipality in vm.getMunicipalitiesByCity($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-on-select="vm.citySelected()" >

JS Controller
vm.getMunicipalitiesByCity = function (cityName) {
            if (cityName != undefined && cityName.length == 3) {
                CalculationEndpointService.municipalitiesByCity({cityName: cityName}, function (result) {
                    vm.municipalities = result.map(
                        function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
            if(cityName.length<3){
                vm.municipalities=[""];
            }
            return vm.municipalities;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `typeahead-min-length` attribute. see https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is more into the AngualrJS structure, I need to force the $digest of that variable in order to see it instantly